# Haskell Data "Error - Control stack overflow"

Tags: haskell, instance

I'm a newbie in Haskell and I am writing my first data structure.

```
 data Nat = Null | N Nat
```

For example:   `5` is `N (N (N (N (N Null))))`

I have to create instances from `Show, Eq, Ord, Num, Enum`

I wrote `Eq` already and it works.

```
instance Eq Nat where
    (==) Null Null = True 
    (==) (N Null) (N Null) = True
    (==) Null (N Null) = False
    (==) Null (N xs) = False
    (==) (N xs) (N xs2) = xs == xs2
```

But when I try this in hugs it gives me an error ("Error- Control stack overflow").

And I can't go on.

```
(N (N Null)) :: Nat
```

What am I missing?

Comment: I think the problem here is with your `Show`. If that is your query, you never call `(==)`. Note furthermore dat Hugs is basically dead (since 2006 iirc), so perhaps you better use GHC.

Comment: You also forgot a case where `(N x) == Null`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and Time! But in ghci it's still a stack overflow

Comment: please post a *minimal woking example*: the text file you load into the compiler as well as the *query*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not covering all the cases. Also, you can simplify your definition by making a last "catch all the rest" case as follows:

```
instance Eq Nat where
    (==) Null   Null    = True 
    (==) (N xs) (N xs2) = xs == xs2
    (==) _      _       = False
```

I have no idea, though, about why your code gave you a stack overflow. It should have given you a non-exhaustive match error, possibly.

Anyway, note that Hugs is now obsolete -- it went 10+ years without updates. You should switch to GHC and use `ghci` instead of Hugs.

---

If you still get stack overflows, it's likely that the issue is in the `Show` instance, where you could have defined an infinite recursion, as Willem Van Onsem points out above.

You should use something like

```
instance Show Nat where
   show Null = "Null"
   show (N x) = "(N " ++ show x ++ ")"
```

By the way, note that some standard instances can be automatically generated, in a correct way. For instance,

```
data Nat = Null | N Nat deriving (Show, Eq, Ord)
```

should just work as intended. It is a nice learning exercise to define these on your own, though.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and Time! But in ghci it's still a stack overflow. >Prelude Null    ->   Stack overflow

Comment: It was my Show method indeed. I forgot using tabs. I didnt know that Haskell is that sensitive. Thank you!